# S3 presigned url access denied

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have this code:

```
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner'
import { Constants } from './constants'

const config = {
  region: Constants.BUCKET_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: Constants.BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: Constants.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  }
}

const s3 = new S3Client(config)

const generateS3UploadUrl = async (key: string): Promise<string> => {
  const command = new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: key,
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
  })

  const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, command, { expiresIn: 3600 })
  return url
}

export { generateS3UploadUrl }
```

I can generate presigned urls successfully, but when i try to use them i can't, i get "Access Denied". My bucket configuration it's default.

I don't care if the bucket is public, i want to be able to store and get the files using presigned urls

Comment: An Amazon S3 pre-signed URL inherits the permissions associated with the AWS credentials used when the pre-signed URL was created. Therefore, the first thing to check is whether the credentials used actually have permission to perform the `PutObject` operation.

Comment: How exactly are you using them? Do your credentials have the permissions to upload? Are you sure your client sends `image/jpeg` as content type when uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it disabling the Public Access Block in permissions and using this bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```